Vue component still not showing in welcome blade php
Why the component vue js still not showing in welcome blade.
Already run this command:

php artisan serve
npm run dev
3.npm run build
php artisan clear:view
vite build
vite build --watch

But still not working
welcome.blade.php
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>Real-Time Notifications</title>
    @vite('resources/css/app.css')
</head>
<body>
<div id="app">
    <example-component></example-component>
</div>
@vite('resources/js/app.js')
</body>
</html>

vite.config.js
import { defineConfig } from 'vite';
import laravel from 'laravel-vite-plugin';
import vue from '@vitejs/plugin-vue';

export default defineConfig({
    plugins: [
        laravel({
            input: [
                'resources/css/app.css',
                'resources/js/app.js',
            ],
            refresh: true,
        }),
        vue({
            template: {
                transformAssetUrls: {
                    base: null,
                    includeAbsolute: false,
                },
            },
        }),
    ],
    resolve: {
        alias: {
            vue: 'vue/dist/vue.esm-bundler.js',
        },
    },
});

app.js
/**
 * First we will load all of this project's JavaScript dependencies which
 * includes Vue and other libraries. It is a great starting point when
 * building robust, powerful web applications using Vue and Laravel.
 */

import './bootstrap';
import { createApp } from 'vue';

/**
 * Next, we will create a fresh Vue application instance. You may then begin
 * registering components with the application instance so they are ready
 * to use in your application's views. An example is included for you.
 */

const app = createApp({});

import ExampleComponent from './components/ExampleComponent.vue';
import NotificationComponent from './components/NotificationComponent.vue';

app.component('notification-component', NotificationComponent);
app.component('example-component', ExampleComponent);

/**
 * The following block of code may be used to automatically register your
 * Vue components. It will recursively scan this directory for the Vue
 * components and automatically register them with their "basename".
 *
 * Eg. ./components/ExampleComponent.vue -> <example-component></example-component>
 */

// Object.entries(import.meta.glob('./**/*.vue', { eager: true })).forEach(([path, definition]) => {
//     app.component(path.split('/').pop().replace(/\.\w+$/, ''), definition.default);
// });

/**
 * Finally, we will attach the application instance to a HTML element with
 * an "id" attribute of "app". This element is included with the "auth"
 * scaffolding. Otherwise, you will need to add an element yourself.
 */

app.mount('#app');

ExampleComponent.vue
<template>
    <div class="container">
        <div class="row justify-content-center">
            <div class="col-md-8">
                <div class="card">
                    <div class="card-header">Example Component</div>

                    <div class="card-body">
                        I'm an example component.ds
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</template>

<script>
    export default {
        mounted() {
            console.log('Component mounted.')
        }
    }
</script>

bootstrap.js
import 'bootstrap';

/**
 * We'll load the axios HTTP library which allows us to easily issue requests
 * to our Laravel back-end. This library automatically handles sending the
 * CSRF token as a header based on the value of the "XSRF" token cookie.
 */

import axios from 'axios';
window.axios = axios;

window.axios.defaults.headers.common['X-Requested-With'] = 'XMLHttpRequest';

/**
 * Echo exposes an expressive API for subscribing to channels and listening
 * for events that are broadcast by Laravel. Echo and event broadcasting
 * allows your team to easily build robust real-time web applications.
 */

// import Echo from 'laravel-echo';

// import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
// window.Pusher = Pusher;

// window.Echo = new Echo({
//     broadcaster: 'pusher',
//     key: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
//     cluster: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER ?? 'mt1',
//     wsHost: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_HOST ?? `ws-${import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER}.pusher.com`,
//     wsPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 80,
//     wssPort: import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_PORT ?? 443,
//     forceTLS: (import.meta.env.VITE_PUSHER_SCHEME ?? 'https') === 'https',
//     enabledTransports: ['ws', 'wss'],
// });


import Echo from 'laravel-echo';
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');

window.Echo = new Echo({
    broadcaster: 'pusher',
    key: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_KEY,
    cluster: process.env.MIX_PUSHER_APP_CLUSTER,
    forceTLS: true
});

to show the component of the vue in the blade file
Console:

Network:


As per [ask] you must paste code here as text, not images. You can [edit] your post. Thanks

Hi @ADyson already updated it thanks for the heads up

Can you add the bootstrap.js code too? the error seems to be inside that file

Already added please check @Daniel

In bootstrap.js
Replace this
window.Pusher = require('pusher-js');
With this
Import Pusher from 'pusher-js';
window.Pusher = Pusher

great thanks in addition I already update the code since the console give me a hint

As a further reference for other developers. require is usually not available on the client side.
